# Change value in plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I created `plist` file to change `background-color` from `WallpaperViewController` to `CalculatorViewController` by change a `value` in `plist` file.
My code works perfect in **iOS** simulator but,on device it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

**WallpaperViewController**

```
- (IBAction)changeBack:(UIButton *)sender {



NSString *buttonname = sender.currentTitle;

NSString *hello = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"The calculator background is %@",nil) ,buttonname];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CB" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];



if ([buttonname isEqualToString:@"iPhone6Calwall"]) {

    [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



} else if ([buttonname isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

        [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

        [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



} else if ([buttonname isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Yellow",nil)]) {

    [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



} else if ([buttonname isEqualToString:@"Brown"]) {

        [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

        [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



} else if ([buttonname isEqualToString:@"Purple"]) {

    [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];



} else if ([buttonname isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {

    [dict setObject:buttonname forKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];

    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

**CalculatorViewController**

```
// Read plist from bundle and get Root Dictionary out of it

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CB" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString *check = [dict objectForKey:@"Calculatorbackground"];





if ([check isEqual:@"iPhone6Calwall"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone6Calwall"]]];

} else if ([check isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BMIbackground"]]];



} else if ([check isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tipbackground"]]];



} else if ([check isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalYellow"]]];



} else if ([check isEqualToString:@"Brown"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalBrown"]]];



} else if ([check isEqualToString:@"Purple"]) {

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalPurple"]]];



}
```

Comment: Please don't radically alter your question. Once you've received an answer that solves your problem,  mark it as accepted and then ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you can not write to the app bundle, use the Document directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSError *error;
BOOL status = [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (status == NO) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error)
}
```

Error parameters are for your benefit, use them. Instead of writeToFile: atomically: use writeToFile:options:error:, check for an error return and then if there is an error check the error parameter to see what the error is.

Comment: I edited the code in topic,Now the background not load (the plist type is dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue last week. You're trying to write to NSBundle mainBundle where you have no permission to do. Use a path into the Documents folder instead.

Comment: I edited the code in topic,Now the background not load (the plist type is dictionary)